# Python Relations with Sets of Tuples

Tags: python, set, tuples, relation

I'm trying to determine whether or not sets of tuples have a certain type of relation. I'm trying to figure out the transitive relation, and the composite relation.

For the transitive relation:

```
 # A relation 'Relation' is called transitive when:
 # ∀ (a, b) ∈ Relation, (b, c) ∈ Relation ==> (a, c) ∈ Relation
```

For example:

```
>>> {(1,1), (1,2), (1,4), (2,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,1), (4,4)} # Should be False
>>> {(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (3,2), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3)} # Should be True
```

For the composite relation:

```
# The composite of relations 'R1' and 'R2' is the relation consisting
# of tuples (a,c), such that (a,b) ∈ R1 and (b,c) ∈ R2
```

For example:

```
{(1,0), (1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (3,0), (3,1)} == R1={(1,1), (1,4), (2,3), (3,1), (3,4)}, R2={(1,0), (2,0), (3,1), (3,2), (4,1)}
# Should return True
```

I am uncertain on how to start coding these functions. Any help to get me started would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:
Here are some other relations I was able to successfully code:

```
# Reflexive Relation
# A relation 'Relation' on a set 'Set' is called reflexive when:
# ∀ a ∈ Set, (a,a) ∈ Relation
def is_reflexive(Set, Relation):
    newSet = {(a, b) for a in Set for b in Set if a == b}
    if Relation >= newSet:
        return True

    return False

# Symmetric Relation
# A relation 'Relation' is called symmetric when:
#  ∀ (a, b) ∈ Relation, (b, a) ∈ Relation
def is_symmetric(Relation):
    if all(tup[::-1] in Relation for tup in Relation):
        return True


    return False
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta actually, the relations are *precisely specified*.

Comment: I fully specified the relations. I'm just not sure where to start on the code lol

Comment: @SergeBallesta an n-ary relation (in mathematics) is merely a collection of n-tuples. So, binary relations are merely sets of pairs, for example. So, the binary relation "less than" on the set of integers {1, 2, 3} is {(1,2), (2,3), (1,3)}. Note, less-than is transitive!

Comment: @Coder117 Anyway, I'm torn, because this is an interesting question, especially to get the CS perspective, but I think you need to show your own attempts first! Please, at least add how you have failed.

Comment: Perhaps I can add how I did some other relations?

Comment: I think you should add a little bit of non-formal exposition about the definition of what a relation is in mathematics. Not all coders are into abstract maths. They can be quite concrete folks! You can use the toy example I posted here. Coders know the less-than relation very well :). I've voted to close, though, because it is too broad. You should elaborate on what you've tried, and how it hasn't worked. Or Try asking on the haskell tag...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have edited my question. I hope you reconsider your vote to close. I always start out my questions broad and edit to make it more precise, as I do not know the answer and the person helping me does, I do not want to get too precise to the point of confusion. I would appreciate it if you looked at my edited question! Thanks!

Comment: @Coder117 what is the counter example for your non-transitive relation? I could have sworn that I noticed it before, but now I can't find it!

Comment: So, for example, `{(1,1), (1,2), (1,4), (2,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,1), (4,3)}` would clearly not be transitive, because (1,4) and (4,3)  but NOT (1,3)

Comment: That is correct. Unfortunately I do not have a counter example for the composite relation.

Comment: @Coder117: If I correctly remember my old maths, transitiveness and composition only concern 2-ary relations, so we could only consider sets of 2-tuples. Right?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Correct we are only dealing with Binary Relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the transitive test, just convert the math definition in Python:

```
def is_transitive(relation):
    for a,b in relation:
        for c,d in relation:
            if b == c and ((a,d) not in relation):
                    # print (a,b),(c,d) # uncomment for tests...
                    return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Do you think you could help me with the composite function as well?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a brute force approach that works. First, we are going to use an "adjacency set" representation, then just test explicitly using a deeply nested for-loop:

```
In [5]: r1 =  {(1,1), (1,2), (1,4), (2,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,1), (4,3)}

In [6]: adjacency = {}
    ...: for a,b in r1:
    ...:     adjacency.setdefault(a,set()).add(b)
    ...:

In [7]: transitive = True

In [8]: for a, related in adjacency.items():
    ...:     for b in related:
    ...:         for c in adjacency[b]:
    ...:             if c not in related:
    ...:                 transitive = False
    ...:                 print("({},{}) and ({},{}) but not ({},{})".format(a, b, b, c, a,c))
    ...:
(1,4) and (4,3) but not (1,3)
(2,1) and (1,4) but not (2,4)
(4,1) and (1,2) but not (4,2)
(4,1) and (1,4) but not (4,4)

In [9]: transitive
Out[9]: False
```

However, for your second example:

```
In [7]: r2 = {(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (3,2), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3)}

In [8]: adjacency = {}
    ...: for a,b in r2:
    ...:     adjacency.setdefault(a,set()).add(b)
    ...:

In [9]: transitive = True

In [10]: for a, related in adjacency.items():
    ...:     for b in related:
    ...:         for c in adjacency[b]:
    ...:             if c not in related:
    ...:                 transitive = False
    ...:                 print("({},{}) and ({},{}) but not ({},{})".format(a, b, b, c, a,c))
    ...:

In [11]: transitive
Out[11]: True
```

Using this data structure should make it a little less horrible from a time-complexity POV.

As for constructing the composite:

```
In [18]: def make_adjacency_set(R):
    ...:     a = {}
    ...:     for x,y in R:
    ...:         a.setdefault(x, set()).add(y)
    ...:     return a
    ...:

In [19]: def make_composite(R1, R2):
    ...:     adj1 = make_adjacency_set(R1)
    ...:     adj2 = make_adjacency_set(R2)
    ...:     composite = set()
    ...:     for a, related in adj1.items():
    ...:         for b in related:
    ...:             for c in adj2.get(b, []):
    ...:                 composite.add((a, c))
    ...:     return composite
    ...:

In [20]: R1={(1,1), (1,4), (2,3), (3,1), (3,4)}; R2={(1,0), (2,0), (3,1), (3,2), (4,1)}

In [21]: make_composite(R1, R2)
Out[21]: {(1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1)}
```

Or, just sticking with sets of tuple:

```
In [25]: composite = set()
    ...: for a, b in R1:
    ...:     for c, d in R2:
    ...:         if b == c:
    ...:             composite.add((a,d))
    ...:
    ...:

In [26]: composite
Out[26]: {(1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1)}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Turns out I was looking for something more like Serge's answer. In case he doesn't reply, do you think you could help me with the composite function in the style that he coded the transitive one? Thanks again either way!

Comment: @Coder117 I'm not sure what you mean by "in that style". But I've posted an implementation...

Comment: try with r={ (1,2) } and check it