# Python Transitive Relations with Sets of Tuples

Tags: python

I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine if this list is transitive or not

```
D1 = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21}
```

I have to determine if r in the domain of D1 is transitive. I have to check every possible tuple

What I have so far

```
def r(x, y):
    R = [[9, 7], [9, 5], [9, 3], [9, 1], [7, 5], [7, 3], [7, 1], [5, 3], [3, 1]]
    return([x, y] in R)

rIsTransitive = True

for a in D1:
    for b in D1:
        for c in D1:
            for d in D1:
                if(r(a, b) and b == c):
                    rIsTransitive = False
                    print('The triple (' + str(a) + ',' + str(b) + ',' + str(c) + ') shows that r is not transitive')


if (rIsTransitive):
    print('The relation r on domain D1 is transitive.')
else:
    print('The relation r on domain D1 is not transitive.')
print(' ')
```

The output should be

```
The triple (5,3,1) shows that r is not transitive
The relation r on domain D1 is not transitive.
```

My output currently

```
The triple (9,5,5) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,5,5) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,5,5) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The triple (9,7,7) shows that r is not transitive
The relation r on domain D1 is not transitive.
```

Comment: why the `for d in D1' you don't use it in the content of the loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Relations with Sets of Tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153333/python-relations-with-sets-of-tuples)

Answer (score 1):

Given comment clarification from Mark Dickinson,

You can iterate trough your list and unpack your sub arrays in one go with `for a,b in s`

then you need 2 loops (see bellow) , one for the first pair, one for the second. Because your set is ordered, you only need to check that b == c and that the array [a,d] is in the set, then you need to output a,b,**d** because otherwise you will see a triplet with b==c.

Assuming you want to stop right after the first non transitive item (5,3,1) then you can break out of the for loop (need a flag and conditional break everyway... or you could use a generator function)

```py
s = [[9, 7], [9, 5], [9, 3], [9, 1], [7, 5], [7, 3], [7, 1], [5, 3], [3, 1]]

def my_non_transitivity_genenerator(value_set):
    for a,b in s:
        for c,d in s:
            yield (b==c and [a,d] not in s,a,b,c,d)

checker = my_non_transitivity_genenerator(s)

for t,a,b,c,d in checker:
    if t:
        print(f'The triple ({a},{b},{d}) is not transitive')
        break
else:
    print('The relation r on domain D1 is transitive.')
```

Comment: This doesn't help the OP: `(3, 1, 1)` does _not_ represent a "non-transitive item". As the OP clearly states, the algorithm should identify `(5, 3, 1)` as the problematic triple (because `r(5, 3)` is `True` and `r(3, 1)` is `True`, but `r(5, 1)` is `False`, while for a transitive relation `r`, if `r(a, b)` is true and `r(b, c)` is true then `r(a, c)` must also be true). The problem is that the OP is not using the correct test for transitivity in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Through you defind all `[X,Y]` in R which `X>Y`, and you want the output be `(5,3,1)`, you could modify the condition and add the statement to stop the loop.

```
def r(x, y):
    R = [[9, 7], [9, 5], [9, 3], [9, 1], [7, 5], [7, 3], [7, 1], [5, 3], [3, 1]]
    return([x, y] in R)

rIsTransitive = True

for a in D1:
    for b in D1:
        for c in D1:
            if(r(a, b) and b > c):
                rIsTransitive = False
                print('The triple (' + str(a) + ',' + str(b) + ',' + str(c) + ') shows that r is not transitive')
                break
        if rIsTransitive == False:
            break


if (rIsTransitive):
    print('The relation r on domain D1 is transitive.')
else:
    print('The relation r on domain D1 is not transitive.')
print(' ')
```